# Call ADB command from Native C++ code and getting result as string

Tags: android, c++

Trying to execute the command `adb shell pwd` from native code inside Android, and displaying the returned `pwd` in the activity, so I wrote:

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_adb_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    // std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    int status =  system("adb shell pwd");

    // I think below code is wrong //

    char buff[100];
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "system ret:[%d]\n",status>>8);
    std::string buffAsStdStr = buff;

    // End of code block which I think is wrong //

    return env->NewStringUTF(buffAsStdStr.c_str()); //env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

And got the out put as `system ret:[127]`

It looks I made a mistake in converting the returned output of the command `system` into a `string`

[image]

Comment: `std::system` - __Return value__ _"...Implementation-defined [`int`] value. ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system  ie `std::system` does not return the result of any command only whether it was invoked sucussfully.

Comment: Does `adb` exist as a command on the Android device? I know that `adb` is a command on the development platform [PC] which talks to a host service on Android but I didn't think `adb` was part of the Android image.

Comment: Related: [Android source `adb` README](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/adb/README.md)